# jQuery click on id by based on data id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have options with data-id and some tabs with ids. I need to simulate the click option data-id to tab id. This is just an example of code. The real code is done but I cant find a solution to simulate this click.

EDITED:
so in the final, there will be a drop-down with some options and tabs. when I click on the first item in the drop-down then opens tab one. when click on option two it needs to open tab two etc. I have data ids on options and ids on tabs. data needs to find id and simulate click.

```js
jQuery('.dropdown-content span').on("click", function(){
       /* here i need help */
        jQuery('data-id').find('same-id like data-id').click();
    });
    
/* just exapmle to open contet */
jQuery('[id^="content"]').on('click', function(){
 jQuery('.content',this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content span{
position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.tabs {
position:relative;
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
margin-top:50px;
}

.tab {
padding:20px;
display:block;
text-align:center;
}

.content {
display:none;
}

.active {
 display:block
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropDownBtn">
    <p>Numbers:</p>
</div>
<div class="dropDownContainer">
    <div id="tabDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <span data-id="content1">1</span>
        <span data-id="content2">2</span>
        <span data-id="content3">3</span>
     </div>
</div>


<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab " id="content1">1
      <span class="content">some content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="content2">2
      <span class="content">some content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="content3">3
      <span class="content">some content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem (like the CSS)

Comment: You only wrote two sentences attempting to explain the problem. We'd be able to help you better if you'd actually explain what you're trying to do, as it stands, the question is not clear, even with all the code you posted. The code also appears to include pseudo code mixed in, and that's confusing because it's not clear if it's the reason for your issue, or if we're supposed to guess what to replace things with.

Comment: @Sergey so in the final there fill be drop-down with some options and tabs. when i click on first item in drop-down then opens tab one.  when click on option two it need to open tab two etc. i have data ids on options and ids on tabs. data needs to find id and simulate click.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sandi, thanks for updating your question and providing more details.

I believe what you're looking for is the `attr(...)` method. See it in action below.

First we use `$(this)` to select the currently clicked element.

Then to extract the value of its `data-id` attribute we do the following:
`const dataAttrVal = $(this).attr('data-id')`

and finally we build the "id selector" by prepending a `#`:
`jQuery('#' + dataAttrVal).click()`

```js
jQuery('.dropdown-content span').on("click", function(){
  // In this context "this" refers to the currently clicked element

  // To extract data from an attribute usually you use the "attr" method
  // like this:
  const dataAttrVal = $(this).attr('data-id');  
  
  jQuery('#' + dataAttrVal).click();
});
    
/* just an example to open content*/
jQuery('[id^="content"]').on('click', function(){
 jQuery('.content',this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#tabDropdown span {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content span{
position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.tabs {
position:relative;
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
margin-top:50px;
}

.tab {
padding:20px;
display:block;
text-align:center;
}

.content {
display:none;
background-color: green;
}

.active {
 display:block
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropDownBtn">
    <p>Numbers:</p>
</div>
<div class="dropDownContainer">
    <div id="tabDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <span data-id="content1">1</span>
        <span data-id="content2">2</span>
        <span data-id="content3">3</span>
     </div>
</div>


<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab" id="content1">Tab 1
      <span class="content">some content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="content2">Tab 2
      <span class="content">some content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="content3">Tab 3
      <span class="content">some content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```